# Schlick's approximation for reflectance when $n_1 = n_2$

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

another raytracer here.

I'm using Schlick's approximation to the Fresnel equations, which is said to be reasonably faithful.

I'm a little puzzled about the situation where the incident ray is just grazing the surface, ie the incident ray is nearly perpendicular to the surface normal. The Schlick approximation seems to require that reflectance approaches 1 in this situation, even if the two indices of refraction are equal.  If the indices are identical, i would expect reflectance to be zero, even at grazing angles.

Reflectance = 1 at grazing angles no matter the materials doesn't match my experience of the world.  For example, those little toy silica gel balls kids play with are basically invisible when immersed in water. Ice in water is similar.

Where am i going astray?

To clarify, i am not asking about total internal reflection, nor am i asking about the amount of light transmitted at an interface when $n_1 = n_2$.

Comment: It's an approximation. You've found a situation where it breaks down.

Comment: Thanks Puk, that's helpful.  I threw in something that takes R to 0 as the indices approach each other. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yt0rn3myyb

Comment: Thanks also for the edits, @Qmechanic.